# DXL DOORS restore attribute text from session

Tags: ibm-doors

I messed up things and now I need to restore like 3000 attributes back to their values.
I changed all the text of attribute of a current view by mistake. Now I want to revert the changes to the session before I made these.

Could anyone help me with an script which restores the attribute from my last session.

Comment: so, this concerns the attribute "Object Text" of a lot of objects and the changes can be identified by a certain session number?

Comment: http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=418 might get you started, also the example script "history example program" in the dxl manual should give you an idea how to iterate over history records.